# Web API 2 - Prompting for Windows Credentials?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api

I just copied a Web API service from localhost to a server running Windows Server 2012 / IIS (exact same binaries as localhost).

Authentication modes are anonymous and basic.

Whenever I try to run an API call, I receive a Windows Authentication prompt?

How is this possible?

Comment: This is likely due to missing NTFS file read/execute permissions.  Make sure that the Application Pool account which is running your service out of IIS has access to the file system location where the actual service binary files reside.  If you need to change NTFS permissions, you may need to recycle IIS to actually have it pick up on the new file system permissions.

Comment: Getting a response from the API (meaning the app pool can access the files), but Windows prompt still appears. I do have code to log to a file, which may be the culprit. Tried giving Modify permission to the app pool identity, and prompt still appears (even restarted IIS).

Comment: This is the canonical list of reasons why it could be doing it: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/258063

Comment: I have an IAuthentication filter and ActionFilterAttribute on one of the methods. I noticed that when either authentication or authorization fails, a "WWW-Authenticate" header is added to the response and seems to be causing the issue. The header isn't added on localhost when I test. 

How do I prevent this header from being added automatically on the other server?

"WWW-Authenticate Header is present: Basic realm='MyDomain'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by returning 200 with error message instead of 401. An HTTP 401 is supposed to return "WWW-Authenticate" header on response, which causes the authentication pop-up.